# Looking for a hand on my jQuery and JS script

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have is in my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/mPuj9/4/

What I tried to do is to disable the button until all of `textbox`es are filled and the `checkbox` is checked. My current code is not good, it let you submit in some cases and I don't know how to work it with the `checkbox`.

***CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.textfield').blur(function() {
        if ($.trim(this.value) == "") {
            $('#btnUpdate').attr("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            $('#btnUpdate').removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#termid').change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('#reservationdetails').empty().addClass('loading').load('../kratisis/forms/' + val + '.php', function() {
            $('#reservationdetails').removeClass('loading')
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please don't post questions containing only links to off-site code. "please fix this blob of code" questions are the very definition of "too localized".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/mPuj9/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').delegate('input:text, input:checkbox', 'blur keyup change', function () {
        if(($('form input:text').filter(function(){ return $.trim(this.value) == ''; }).length > 0)
           || ($('form input:checked').length == 0)){
          $('#btnUpdate').attr("disabled", true);
        }
      else {
            $('#btnUpdate').removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Giorkouros - Take a look at this fiddle.

Comment: This works great but one small question. The submit button is disables or enabled when the user clicks outside of the textbox. Is there any way to make that possible while something is insert into the textbox? I am asking because I use the jQuery datepicker for one textbox.

Comment: This is perfect. When you visit Greece contact me for a free bottle at bouzoukia my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could do this, which also works if someone presses enter in a text box, or if the browser autofilled an input:

```
$(function() {
    $("form button").attr("disabled", true); //disable buttons at first
    var inputs = 0; //keep count of the inputs
    $("form input, form select, form textarea").each(function() {
        inputs++; //increment counter
        $(this).keypress(function() {
            if ($.trim($(this).val()) != "") { //if the value isnt empty
                inputs--; //decrement counter
                if (inputs == 0) { //if theyre all filled in
                    $("form button").attr("disabled", false);
                }
            }
        }).trigger("keypress"); //in case it was autofilled by the browser
    });
    $("form").submit(function(e) { //prevent the form being submitted by pressing enter
        if (inputs != 0) { //if they arent all filled in
            alert("Some fields aren't filled in. Please fix them and try again."); //tell the user
            e.preventDefault(); //cancel sending the form
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the fiddle with your code http://jsfiddle.net/mPuj9/6/ that I still didnt make it work. Can you look at it please ?

Comment: @Girokouros I'll do that now.

Comment: I've found the problem: I set the button to be disabled instead of enabled when everything's filled in. [Here's the link to the working version on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkaEx/1/).

Comment: Hi again. I filled the form like a normal person will do but the button is still disabled. When I backspace and type again in a field it works....

Comment: @Giorkouros You need to click out of the text box for the code to be triggered. You can change where ever it says “change” to “keypress” to make it check the contents on every key press. I'll update the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not using .each() for the text fields.  You're checking the one that was recently changed to see if it's value is "", but you're not checking each one.